# Black splash screen - Phonegap Build (Android)

Tags: android, cordova, build, config, phonegap-build

I'm using this code to add my Splash Screen in the config file with Phonegap Build:

```
<gap:splash src="mdpi-logo.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="hdpi-logo.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="xhdpi-logo.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="xxhdpi-logo.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xxhdpi" />
```

But, when I installed my app on Android plataform, It doesn't work, It shows a black screen before it shows the app.

Comment: are the images in the same path as `config.xml`?

Comment: Yes! Do I need to create a new folder?

Comment: I decided to change gap:qualifier with gap:density and it worked out but it seems like, It takes one of the images showing it pixelated

Answer (score 1):

If that can help you when I used qualifier instead of density, if I want that the Splash Screen work I have to configure :

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
```

instead of

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="www/assets/images/ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="www/assets/images/mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/assets/images/hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="www/assets/images/xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

and had to scale images exactly to same size as specified at

```
platforms/android/assets/www/res/screen/android
```

remember exact size, not ratio.