# PhoneGap build android splash screen not working

Tags: android, cordova, gruntjs, splash-screen

I'm having a couple of issues with the Android splash screen using PhoneGap 3.5.0. When I do a build, I'm seeing some weird results with the splash screen files in platforms/android/res:

- Some folders copy over the splash.png file as expected (drawable, drawable-land, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi)
- Some folders copy over splash.png and also include a default PhoneGap splash screen with the name screen.png (drawable-land-hdpi, drawable-land-ldpi, drawable-land-mdpi, drawable-land-xhdpi)
- Some folders only include a default PhoneGap splash screen with the name screen.png (drawable-port-hdpi, drawable-port-ldpi, drawable-port-mdpi, drawable-port-xhdpi)

The second issue is that despite splash images being in the folders, when I test the app I see a black screen rather than either my custom splash screens or a default PhoneGap splash screen.

I've found several articles around this issue, but none of the fixes worked for me. Some of the things I've tried included:

- Pare down the number of image options and use a 9-slice image ([Black splash screen - Phonegap Build (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212966/black-splash-screen-phonegap-build-android))
- Swapping :qualifier and :density in my config.xml (http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/11/phonegap-build-adds-some-new-features/)
- Adding the org.apache.cordova.splashscreen plugin
- Adding SplashScreen and SplashScreenDelay preferences to my config.xml (also in conjunction with the above) ([phonegap dont show splashscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156326/phonegap-dont-show-splashscreen))

A few other notes:

- The splash screen works fine in the iOS build.
- I'd like to solve this in the PhoneGap build... I'd like to avoid editing Android-specific files
- I wonder if it's possible that I need to clear out a cache somewhere. I've had success with the Android splash screen in earlier versions of this project and have since updated my versions of PhoneGap.
- I have a grunt-phonegap setup going, but I see the same errors if I use `phonegap local build` rather than `grunt platform-build`.
- My splash links look like `<gap:splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-hdpi/splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="land-hdpi" />`

If anybody has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them. Thanks!

Comment: have to got any solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

If that can help you when I used qualifier instead of density, if I want that the Splash Screen work I have to configure :

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
```

instead of

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the config.xml add the following keys:

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
  <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
<preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried *everything*, and then I figured to ignore the minimum size and make my splash.png image in my resources folder 5000px by 3000px. Then it worked. So: If all else fails, try making the splash image ENORMOUS.